# How to change the shortcut to scroll?

Tags: shortcut-keys, touchpad, mouse-scroll

I want to change the shortcut to scroll. Instead of using the edge of my (buggy) touchpad (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32280/mouse-wheel-jumpy-on-scrolling)), I would like to make my own shortcut with the keyboard keys.
Is it possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I did it. It is easy once we know *how* to do...

1) [Install XDoTool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool) and [Compiz](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)

```
sudo aptitude install xdotool compizconfig-settings-manager
```

2) Open Compiz (Menu > System > Preferences > CompizConfig Manager)

```
ccsm
```

3) Go to commands and add this lines:

```
xdotool click --clearmodifiers 4  

xdotool click --clearmodifiers 5
```

[image]

Hope I enjoy ;-)

Comment: Ok. I'm glad to help (especially myself ;-) )