# Jumpy and wonky mouse wheel scroll ubuntu gnome 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, gnome, mouse, mouse-scroll, mouse-wheel

i have an XTECH XTM-510 mouse

my problem is that the mouse wheel acts not only jumpy but wonky, like sometimes it wont scroll, and when i scroll down it would scroll up or scroll down and on the last scroll it would instead scroll up, it would also act this wonky when i scroll up

it happens on every app, window, whatever, even on the shell vol and bright controls.

this problem also happened on a windows 7 desktop but it disappeared when i installed Microsoft Intellipoint Drive (a driver setup for microsoft crappy mouses), all i did after installing that driver was select the mouse most similar to mine and set scroll acceleration at 2, the problem was non-existent on both windows 8 and 10

i've already read the other questions that are similar to mine, but none of them had an answer to my problem, or at least not one that i could understand or implement

for example: [Mouse wheel jumpy on scrolling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32280/mouse-wheel-jumpy-on-scrolling) the last answer, last paragraph captioned solution seems like something that can work but i have no least idea on how to implement such solution

so now having no idea how to fix this problem i decided to post my question here

Comment: I have same problem with Dell KM113 wireless mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and searched for an answer -- then I tried a different mouse, and the problem went away.  Turns out the scroll wheel on my mouse was just dirty inside, and when I cleaned it (I blew it off with a can of compressed air), it worked fine. YMMV of course.

Answer (score 0):

See also [Mouse wheel doesn't scroll up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279994/mouse-wheel-doesnt-scroll-up)

If it is a wireless mouse try connecting the dongle with a USB extension cord, locate the dongle where the computer case will not block the signal,
worked for me on 2 computers.