# Mouse wheel doesn't scroll up

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll

Logitech M305 was working properly for close to 10 years. suddenly the scroll wheel only scrolls up a few lines before stopping. I scroll down the page without issue, but when I reverse to scroll up it only goes a few lines. Have been searching solutions proposed in "similar questions" to no avail. Switching on natural scrolling appears to make it worse.

Comment: Buy a new mouse. 10 years is enough.

Comment: Just tried another logitech mouse from another system and it works. But is changing the hardware really a solution for our problems?

Comment: Yes, it is not a software problem. The mouse is broken.

Comment: Wait wait wait; hold on.  Did/Does the mouse work on other devices? (Windows, other Linux systems, etc?) If that's the case the mouse is not broken. Although, I can't disagree 10 years+ is considered,  old. But are we really sure the mouse is broken? Edit: does the  (I don't know what they are called) 'left-right scroll-clicks' (That is used to repeatedly scroll) ?

Comment: It's a bad mouse. Probably dirt in it. Squirt just a little WD-40 in around both sides of the mouse wheel, move the wheel both directions for a bit, retry on computer. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 0):

First unplug the mouse. In the battery compartment there are probably a couple of screws, open the case. Then blow out the wheel sensor with air (by mouth or canned air, etc.).

A few drops of isopropyl (rubbing) alcohol in the wheel sensor can clean it out nicely, the alcohol will evaporate quickly.

If it is a wireless USB mouse try connecting the dongle with a USB extension and put it where the signal is not blocked by the computer case, I tried this on a problem mouse and it improved performance.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of this myself. Wow. The dust was so packed in there! Funny thing is I've done this mouse clean-up before. Senior moment, perhaps. Thanks @b-fife