# usb mouse middle wheel jumps back a little when scrolling

Tags: mouse-scroll, mouse-wheel

I am using a USB Mouse with scrolling middle wheel (model "trust"). The issue is when I use the scroll wheel it moves a bit in the opposite direction before scrolling in the expected direction (I suppose it is a kind of animation to feel more "natural" the movement, but is very annoying..)
I checked with xinput, and can't find a parameter to fix that:

```
xinput list
USB Optical Mouse                           id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

then:

```
~ : xinput list-props 19
Device 'USB Optical Mouse':
    Device Enabled (169):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (171): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (305):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (306):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (319):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (320):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (321):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (565): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (566): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (567):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (568):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (322): -0.735294
    libinput Accel Speed Default (323): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (569):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (570):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (571):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (324): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (325): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (290): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (291):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (292):    0, 0
    Device Node (293):  "/dev/input/event22"
    Device Product ID (294):    7119, 5
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (307):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (308):   1
```

I tried with `Accel Speed (322)` but zeroing just set cursor to max speed, not related to wheel. 
How can I disable that little jump in the opposite direction when scrolling, and if possible, smooth the scrolling effect?

Comment: I think that its a hardware problem. I also face this issue since my mouse fell over multiple times. Try to use another mouse to see whether the problem persists.

Comment: Unless mouse is new would open it up carefully and give good cleaning.  Other thing might be you moving the mouse a tiny faction when scrolling.  Look carefully for screw/s when opening, some just clip together.

Comment: Similar problem was solved in another [question](https://askubuntu.com/a/101920/1185670)